# Is there a way to bypass the android runtime request permissions with NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-native-library

I just would like to know if there is a way to use the camera and storage without request it in runtime and without to set targetSdkVersion to 21, thanks in advance and sorry if this question sounds dumb in some manner.

**Edit 1:** I don't necessarily mean to bypass, I would like to know if the android permissions are needed in runtime if I use the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

All of the same restrictions apply. You need to make the permission request in Java or over JNI.